# Questions of offset and clear in VBA

Tags: vba

I am totally new in VBA. Suppose

```
A = Range("D1")
```

but it seems not allowed to use

```
A.offset(1,1)?
```

And how to clear all the content I added in the new cells before if the area is not known?

By the way, to clear a known area would you use

```
Range(A.offset(1,1), A.offset(3,3)).Clear?
```

Comment: If `A` is a `Range` object, you need to `Set A = Range("D1")`.  If `A` is a string or numeric variable type `A = Range("D1")` is equivalent to `A = Range("D1").Value`.  It would help if you showed how you declared the variable `A`.  (If you **haven't** declared it, then it is defaulting to not be a `Range` object because of the missing `Set`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly use a Range variable you need to do things like this

```
Dim A As Range        'Declare new Range
Set A = Range("D1")   'Set the Range
```

Then you can easily access to the Offset by doing this

```
A.Offset(1, 1).value  'Access the value on a case with an offset of 1 row and 1 column
```

If you want to clear a known area (A Range as it seems to be in your example) you can proceed like this

```
A.Clear 'Clear all values in your range
```